# Issues with apt-get install vlc

Tags: camera, apt, vlc

I am using a RPi 2 B and Raspbian

I am trying the following command via ssh to install VLC

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

I also tried

```
sudo apt-get install vlc --fix-missing
```

I get two prompts about the amount of space it will take up and verified sources.

But then I see a string of 404 errors and then it just ends:

**Output:**

```
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libvncclient0 armhf 0.9.9+dfsg2-6.1+deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main vlc-data all 2.2.1-1~deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libvlccore8 armhf 2.2.1-1~deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libvlc5 armhf 2.2.1-1~deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main vlc-nox armhf 2.2.1-1~deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main vlc armhf 2.2.1-1~deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main vlc-plugin-notify armhf 2.2.1-1~deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main vlc-plugin-samba armhf 2.2.1-1~deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/libv/libvncserver/libvncclient0_0.9.9+dfsg2-6.1+deb8u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/v/vlc/vlc-data_2.2.1-1~deb8u1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/v/vlc/libvlccore8_2.2.1-1~deb8u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/v/vlc/libvlc5_2.2.1-1~deb8u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/v/vlc/vlc-nox_2.2.1-1~deb8u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/v/vlc/vlc_2.2.1-1~deb8u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/v/vlc/vlc-plugin-notify_2.2.1-1~deb8u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/v/vlc/vlc-plugin-samba_2.2.1-1~deb8u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
```

**Background:**
I had already checked for upgrades and updates via apt-get just a few minutes before trying to install vlc.  Any idea what I can do to get this installed? I am trying to stream video to my VLC player on my laptop which is on the same network.

Comment: 1) have you donne a `sudo apt-get update` right before `sudo apt-get install vlc`? -- 2) if yes, maybe the server was offline and try it now again, or tomorrow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the URL the apt-get was looking for at the Raspbian mirror I realized it was looking for an older version of VLC which was no longer hosted on the mirror. I checked out the mirror URL in the browser to figure out what was going on.

Even though I ran apt-get update prior to installing VLC yesterday, I went ahead and ran it again... and of course this time, when it was looking for the version of VLC, it was getting the correct version number in the URL.

Long story short, DJCrashdummy's recommendation worked:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: After update I ran upgrade. I had to run update again to get vlc listed